# What is the best way to present long texts with titles and subtitles?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text

I am having a bit of an impasse here about my small project.

I am working on an easy application where people can click on topic titles and read instructions on different topics. I have a long text file that goes like this:

> How deep is the ocean
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Facts about dinasours
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

What is the best way to store this data and retrieve in my screen? Should I keep them in seperate txt files, save in database, or define in a file as a const and call with a function? Which one would work faster, properly, and securely?

Thank you for any answer in advance.

Comment: what is the file size of your long text file? less than 10MB?

Comment: Yes it is even less than 5 MB. It is just a 500-750 pages of text.